# Always show Next/Previous using the_post_pagination in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Basically i just want to always show The pagination which wil be:

`Previous` `1` `2` `Next`

At this moment mine is working as is but on page 1 not displaying previous(disabled). And for page 2 not displaying next(disabled).

Code:

```
// Previous/next page navigation.
   the_posts_pagination( array(
       'prev_text' => 'Previous',
       'next_text' =>'Next'
   ));
```

Current Outcome **(page 1):**

`1` `2` `Next`

Expected Outcome **(page 1):**

`Previous(disabled)` `1` `2` `Next`

Current Outcome **(page 2):**

`Previous` `1` `2`

Expected Outcome **(page 2):**

`Previous` `1` `2` `Next(disabled)`

Comment: add another arg in array `prev_next => True` and let me know if its work or not.

Comment: @raju_eww thanks, thats not working. added it as `'prev_next' => True` and not showing.

Comment: please see this one :https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop

Comment: @raju_eww the link provided is not helping at all do you understand the question, it has nothing to do with custom post types.

Comment: yes i got your question perfectly please `mid_size` parameter and also if not works then you have to set it display:block using css

Comment: oky so `mid_size` is used for the numbering 2 would be the paramater then you know this? So its not helpful, secondly using display:block in css , i guess this is to show the previous button? but its not even showing in the HTML so how it makes no sense. Thanks for trying to help i guess

Comment: Had same issue. Thanks to Jonathan G. Bastiat. Problem solved [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52638/pagination-how-do-i-always-show-previous/61579#61579?newreg=45a542e71b1d4133ab183458ca6e97e3)

Answer (score 1):

This one will work just fine:

```
add_filter( 'navigation_markup_template',  'my_posts_pagination', 10, 2 );
function my_posts_pagination($template, $class){
    global $wp_query;
    
    $total   = isset( $wp_query->max_num_pages ) ? $wp_query->max_num_pages : 1;
    $current = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? (int) get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $first = $last = '';
    
    if($current == 1)
        $first = '<span class="prev inactive">Previous</span>';
    
    if($current == $total)
        $last = '<span class="next inactive">Next</span>';
    
    $template = '
    <nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation" aria-label="%4$s">
        <h2 class="screen-reader-text">%2$s</h2>
        <div class="nav-links">
        '.$first.'
        %3$s
        '.$last.'
        </div>
    </nav>';
    return $template;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is dependent on being within the loop and thus using the global $wp_query variable, but sometimes you want to generate a pagination for a custom query. This should work for both cases.

```php
add_filter( 'paginate_links_output', 'my_paginate_links_output', 10, 2 );


function my_paginate_links_output( $output, $args )
{
    if( $args['current'] == 1 )
    {
        $prev = '<span class="prev page-numbers inactive">'.$args['prev_text'].'</span>';
        $output = $prev . "\n" . $output;
    }

    if( $args['total'] == $args['current'] )
    {
        $next = '<span class="next page-numbers inactive">'.$args['next_text'].'</span>';
        $output .= "\n" . $next;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```
<?php

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$query_args = (
    array(
        'post_type' => array('wordpress'),
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'orderby' => 'date', 
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'paged'=> $paged,
        )
    );

$wp_query = new WP_Query($query_args);

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()){
        $wp_query->the_post();

        $wp_postType = get_post_type();
        $wp_postId = get_the_ID();
        $wp_title = get_the_title(); 
        $wp_post_date = get_the_date('F Y', $wp_postId);
        $wp_content = wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 32, '...' );

        echo "<p>" .$wp_title. "</p>";
    }

    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; // need an unlikely integer       
    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));            
        $paginate_links = paginate_links(array(
            'type' => 'array',
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => 'page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'show_all' => true,
            'prev_next' => false,
            ));

        $prev = '<span class="next-prev-btn previous-page"> Prev </span>';
        if($current_page > 1){
            $prev = '<a class="next-prev-btn previous-page" href="'.get_pagenum_link($current_page - 1).'"> Prev </a>';
        }
        
        $next = '<span class="next-prev-btn next-page"> Next </span>';
        if($current_page != $total_pages){
            $next = '<a class="next-prev-btn next-page" href="'.get_pagenum_link($current_page + 1).'"> Next </a>';
        }

        $pagination_link = $paginate_links;
        if($total_pages >= 5){
            if(($current_page+5) > $total_pages){
                $pagination_link = array_slice($paginate_links, ($total_pages - 5), 5);
            } else {
                $pagination_link = array_slice($paginate_links, ($current_page - 1), 5);
            }
        }

        echo '<div class="wordpress-pagenation">';
        for( $i = 0; $i < count($pagination_link); $i++){
            if($i == 0) echo $prev;
            if($i < 5) echo $pagination_link[$i];
            if($i == count($pagination_link) - 1) echo $next;
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

?>
```